# Can App Clip be used in an iOS Cocoapods project?

Tags: ios, wwdc, apple-appclips

Our App was created in 2018 mid using Swift 4, and other 3rd party depended with Cocoapods.
I add one Clip target, the project structure is different from that given by the download link under session. Run this target, here are the crash errors:

```
Reason: image not found

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57185773-B735-4EE5-BB51-790DF004A85B/kt_iOS_Clip.app/kt_iOS_Clip
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib
```

Here is Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target '<Main App>' do
    use_frameworks!
  
    pod 'SnapKit' , '4.2.0'                     
    pod 'Alamofire' , '4.7.3' 
    ......                  
    
  target '<Main App>Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
  
  swift_41_pod_targets = ['Spring','PKHUD', 'FSPagerView', 'SQLite.swift','FaveButton']
  
  post_install do | installer |
      
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == 'Cache'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  level = '-Osize'
                  config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = level
                  puts "Set #{target.name} #{config.name} to Optimization Level #{level}"
              end
          end
          if swift_41_pod_targets.include?(target.name)
              
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  
                  config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
                  
              end
              
          end
          
      end
      
  end

  target '<Main App>UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Answer (score 16):

As other answers mentioned, separate app clip target and `use_modular_headers!` worked for me

```rb
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'MainAppTarget' do
  
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

  target 'MainAppTargetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'AppClipTarget' do
  
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  target 'AppClipTargetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'AppClipTargetUITests' do
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding another target in my podfile which pointed to the AppClip target

Ref: https://www.natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/

Comment: not work, use 'use_modular_headers!' instead of 'use_frameworks!' .

Comment: It worked for me, when I just duplicated Target (for AppClip) in Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

YES, but NO at present （2020.7.15）.

igor-makarov had commit an app clip support to master, now just wait for next CocoaPods release.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/commit/3a5deed0adfa306307027753898cca5e23be14bd

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to do it is having another target (in my case I placed it outside the main one, because I only want a few pods).

However, Cocoapods needs to update something to export/setup everything right. Since App Clips were introduced recently, Cocoapods hasn't released a new stable version with the fix (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/9882). So we just have to wait a bit, I guess. In the meantime, you can add the Embed Pods Frameworks manually and it will work fine.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652683?login=true

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is doing:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Cocoapods latest stable release at the time of this post was not supporting the app clip target with cocoaPods.